# Haskell: should be of form <variable> :: <type>

Tags: xml, haskell

i am developing a small program but i'm stuck with an error.

I have an xml file that i parse, and i get the info that i want in with a function. Structure looks like this:

```
takeall :: [Element] -> (String,String,(String,String),(String,String))
```

Works fine. Next i have some more functions, that basicly make a virtual board with coordinates. If it's empty it will just return spaces in the strings, if not it will return the info i took up there without the first pair of strings. That pair represents the coordinates and i don't need that anymore

So that function looks like this:

```
vboard :: [Element] -> [[(String,String, (String,String))]]
```

if i print this out, this is just fine.

Now this is the part where it gets messy. I want to make a new board based on the vboard result. So i have two functions. First one is transform

```
transform :: (String,String,(String,String)) -> [String]
transform (p,o,(pl,ml)) | (p,o,(pl,ml)) == ("A","N",("","")) = ["aaa","aaa","aaa"]
transform (p,o,(pl,ml)) | (p,o,(pl,ml)) == ("B","N",("","")) = ["bbb","bbb","bbb"]
transform (p,o,(pl,ml)) | (p,o,(pl,ml)) == ("C","N",("","")) = ["ccc","ccc","ccc"]
```

As you may see, this is just for a single element. To use this i implement another function.

```
final :: [[(String,String,(String,String))]] -> [[[String]]]
final l = map (map (transform)) l
```

Ok so if i had a this for a vboard "results", a board with two lines it would look something like this right?

```
[[("A","N",("","")),("A","N",("",""))],
 [("B","N",("","")),("C","N",("",""))]]
```

then if i apply final function to this result i want the outcome to be

```
[[["aaa","aaa","aaa"],["aaa","aaa","aaa"]]
 [["bbb","bbb","bbb"],["ccc","ccc","ccc"]]]
```

but when i run this in ghci it give me an error

```
Invalid type signature final [[(String,String,(String,String))]] -> [[[String]]]
Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

i am new to haskell(and english isn't my first language so i don't understand some more technical stuff), so can you explain what this error means and how should i fix it?

Regards

EDIT: You can have a look in the full code in here

http://paste2.org/pms66kdm

it has different names on the functions, but you can spot them easly.

Comment: It might be a problem with your definition of `transform`.  If you're using guards, you don't have to retype the `transform (p,o,(pl,ml))` part repeatedly, just line up your guards (`|`) on following lines.

Comment: If I do `> type Funky = (String,String,(String,String))`, `> let transform :: Funky -> [String]; transform = undefined`, `> let final :: [[Funky]] -> [[[String]]]; final = map (map transform)` it type checks for me in GHC

Comment: Give me a sec to try it ill give you the result :) Thanks for your time to help :)

Comment: If you need some help reformatting your guards, look at [Learn You A Haskell's](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) examples.

Comment: Nop, it still gives me the same error but now instead of [[(String,String...etc]] it says [[Funky]]

Comment: No problem with the guards, i just had that for testing purposes :P just copied the first line multiple times and changed the "A","B","C".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43461/discussion-between-pedro-lino-and-bheklilr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem-

```
drawfinal2 l :: [[Funky]] -> [[[String]]]
```

You have an extra l in the definition.  If you remove it, the problem should go away.

Comment: Ok nice eye :D Now i have a new problem.

How can i change the transform function so it only needs the first two parameters? I just want to take it if p and the o matches and ignore the rest.

Comment: `transform ("A","N",_) = ["aaa","aaa","aaa"]`....  The "_" matches anything, and you don't need a guard here, by typing in the strings you enforce that only that case will be pattern matched in this case.

Comment: Hi there jamshidh, the problem with that is that i have to do one by one. can you come in the chat so i can explain in more detail? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43461/discussion-between-pedro-lino-and-bheklilr

Answer (score 0):

To debug type issues like these, I try to comment out the offending type declaration (in your case `final :: [[...` and compile with -Wall to see what type GHC infers by itself - if it at all compiles.

GHC gives you the awesome tool of type inference, it's worth using.